# ModelSerializer relations with different handling of GET/POST requests

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django Rest Framework and I'm trying to find a concise way to handle GET and POST requests differently. I have a Post serializer with a related User field (`created_by`) in a 1-to-many relationship. Essentially, I'd like to be able to create Posts using the User's `username` slug, but return a custom serializer `UserSerializerPublic` on GET requests. Such as:

POST request data fields:

- username (a slug)
- post title
- ...

GET request output:

- user (an object containing `username`, `first_name`, etc.)
- post title
- ...

My Post serializer looks like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        lookup_field = 'slug'
```

My User serializer looks like this:

```
class UserSerializerPublic(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        lookup_field = 'username'
```

With this setup, I can create a new Post using the user's `username` as a string field, but the GET request only returns the `username` slug. If I want to retrieve the Post using my custom User serializer, I understand that I have to use `created_by = UserSerializerPublic()` on `PostSerializer`. This, of course, creates an error on POST requests. I don't understand which methods I have to override (if any) to achieve the intended result in both cases. Do I need to create separate serializers for GET and POST?

Trying to use a single serializer for GET and POST requests with different fields. Can't do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework is provided class based ApiView.

ApiView provided separate methods for handle http methods for CRUD like ( get,post,put,patch, delete) you can use different http methods as per your requirement

Refer this link

https://www.google.com/amp/s/iq.opengenus.org/crud-application-with-django/amp/

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the issue by overriding the view's get() method and replacing the `created_by` slug string with a UserSerializerPublic serializer's data.